# Angular 2 and Laravel 5.3 API call error on POST Request is empty on controller

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel-5.3

I am building an API service using laravel 5.3 and a client in angular 2. When I try to submit a login form as JSON data then the request data array is empty `[]` in the login controller (Laravel). I tested the API using the postman extension and it works and returns a 200 status code. But when angular sends a POST request I am *not* receiving anything on my controller.

Angular 2 Post call:

```
private authUrl = 'http://localhost:35656/api/authenticate';
var payload = JSON.stringify({ "email": email, "password": password });
    console.log(payload);
    return this.http.post(this.authUrl, payload, {
        //headers: headers
    }).map((response: Response) => {var status = response.json().status;});
```

Laravel Route

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
Route::post('authenticate', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticate');
```

Laravel Controller

```
 /**
 * Return a JWT
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    //$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $credentials = $request->all(); // IS EMPTY
    //$credentials = 'testing...';
    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'error' => $credentials]);
}
```

If I do this in my POST call from Angular then it works.

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:35656/api/authenticate?email=xxx@eeeee.com&password=xxxxx', '')
        .map((response: Response) => {});
```

My Laravel Sever is http://localhost:35656 and Angular 2 is on http://localhost:3000.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `application/json` to your headers.

Comment: after add header on request, I have this error `Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` I am stuck with this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I added this `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key');` and fixed the server problem. Thank you @vinit-sarvade ... It works now!

Comment: Ah.. yes. You would need to update the headers onto your server to accept the new headers that are being passed in. Usually if the `content-type` and `Accept` headers are not present, the data gets passed into PHP body for which you would need to read it through PHP input stream `php://input`. But that would not be recomended.